# GWT request .with method

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I'm sorry in advance if this rather n00bish question actually has an answer in the documentation which I've just failed to find, but

I'm still relatively new to GWT, and try as I might I can't find an explanation of what the request.with(String...) method actually does which I can understand. Please can someone explain to me in words of one sylable what this method does and why you'd use it?

thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed is in the doc: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory#relationships

By default, entity proxies referenced from the entity proxy/ies you're fetching are **not** fetched (properties will simply be `null` on the client-side). You have to explicitly ask for them using `with()`, passing the name (can be a dotted path too) of the properties you want to fetch.

Comment: thank you very much, I had found that reference in the docs but not understood it, your wording makes more sense to me. Just to make sure I now understand correctly, if I fire a request which returns an entityProxy, and that entityProxy in turn contains a second entityProxy as a property, then the property will come back null unless I specifically ask for it by doing request.with("propertyName").

Comment: I also seem to be finding that ValueProxies are returning as null unless I explicitly include the in the .with() - is that expected behavior as well?

Comment: Yes. But everything inside the value proxy will then come without the need for `.with()`